nginx servrer with default website and 2 locations
I'm trying to setup a simple nginx web server with a default website and 2 locations.
default website works, but https://acme.com/pierwsza or /druga gets me to 404, why?
erver {
  listen 443 ssl default_server;  # Enforce HTTPS with port 443

  index index.html;

  server_name _;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/acme.com/fullchain.pem;  # Replace with your actual certificate path
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/acme.com/privkey.pem;  # Replace with your actual key path

  # Serve "welcome to nginx" for the root path
  location / {
    root /var/www/default;
    # index index.html;
  }

  # Serve content from /pierwsza directory
  location /pierwsza {
    root /var/www/pierwsza/;
    # index index.html;
  }

  # Serve content from /druga directory
  location /druga {
    root /var/www/druga/;
    # index index.html;
  }

  # Access log for all requests
  access_log /var/log/nginx/acme.com_access.log;

  # Error log configuration
  error_log /var/log/nginx/acme.com_error.log;
}

My sites-enabled look like this:
root@ubuntu:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled# ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 May 11 15:05 default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

My sites-available has only default config file
My /var/www look like this:
root@ubuntu:/var/www# sudo ls -alh default/
total 204K
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 12 21:46 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K May 12 21:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  258 May 12 21:46 error404.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187K May 12 21:45 error404.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  615 May 11 15:05 index.html
root@ubuntu:/var/www# sudo ls -alh pierwsza/
total 208K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K May 20 22:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K May 12 21:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  258 May 20 22:14 error404.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187K May 20 22:52 error404.jpg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 12 21:22 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  792 May 12 21:22 index.html
root@ubuntu:/var/www/druga# ls -alh
total 208K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K May 20 22:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4.0K May 12 21:14 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  258 May 20 22:14 error404.html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 187K May 20 22:52 error404.jpg
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K May 12 21:23 images
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  794 May 12 21:23 index.html

What is wrong here?

You have the wrong root value for location /pierwsza and location /druga. In both cases it should be root /var/www; as the path element pierwsza and druga is already included in the URL.
See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root
